# Content of textarea is not empty after deleting it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a simple textarea in html like this:

```html
<textarea name="sitetitl" id="sitetitle" class="feld" maxlength="255" data-check-length="255">
</textarea>
```

Now let's say there is text in this textarea, because it loads something from the database and puts it in there:

```html
<textarea name="sitetitl" id="sitetitle" class="feld" maxlength="255" data-check-length="255">
Here is some text from the database
</textarea>
```

Now when I delete that text manually by pressing the return key on my keyboard, the text gets deleted visually. But when I inspect the element it still says that text is in there.

The problem here is that there is a specific button which appears when there is no text in the textarea. This also works as intended. This button has a function that generates text in that textarea on click. If there is text in that area, a jquery popup will appear, asking the user if he wants to override the current text. But there is no text, because I deleted it. So the popup comes, because on inspecting the element, you can still see the text, although I deleted it.

```js
    const $textfield = $('#sitetitle');

    if ($textField.text().trim() !== '' || $textField.val().trim() !== '') {
            console.log($textField.text().trim());
            console.log($textField.val().trim());
            overrideConfirmDialog($response, $textField, $generationButton, seoOptionPart);
        } else {
                $textField.text($response);
                updateAllCheckFields();
        }
```

Comment: Please provide the code to get more efficient help

Comment: _"But when I inspect the element it still says that text is in there."_ - yes, because of the difference between "attribute" and "property", see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html

Comment: We need a proper [mre] from you that illustrates the problem, not just some vague verbal explanation.

Comment: Added a little code snippet. I'm using jquery btw btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<textarea>` is different from `<input type='text'>`, both have `value` attribute, but only `textarea` could have `textContent` between opening and closing tag.

Changing the text inside the `textarea` will change the `value` so when you want to make some condition based on that, you could say:

```
// jQuery
var textarea = $("textarea");
if (textarea.val()) // do this
else // do that

// javascript
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
if (textarea.value) // do this
else // do that
```

to demonstrate the difference, check the below example:

### Javascript

```js
function check(){
  const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
  console.log('textContent = ', textarea.textContent);
  console.log('value = ', textarea.value);
}

function changeText(){
  const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
  textarea.innerText = textarea.value;
  console.log('textContent = ', textarea.textContent);
  console.log('value = ', textarea.value);
}
```

```html
<p>Change the text then press the button</p>
<textarea name="test" rows="6" cols="30">
Text from db
</textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="check()">Check value and text</button>
<p>Press below button to change the text in DOM depending on enterd value</p>
<button onclick="changeText()">Change text content</button>
```

### jQuery

```js
function check(){
  var textarea = $("textarea");
  console.log('text() = ', textarea.text());
  console.log('val() = ', textarea.val());
}

function changeText(){
  var textarea = $("textarea");
  textarea.text(textarea.val());
  console.log('text() = ', textarea.text());
  console.log('val() = ', textarea.val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Change the text then press the button</p>
<textarea name="test" rows="6" cols="30">
Text from db
</textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="check()">Check value and text</button>
<p>Press below button to change the text in DOM depending on enterd value</p>
<button onclick="changeText()">Change with text()</button>
```

This means that whenever the DOM is parsed and loaded, the `textContent` between opening and closing tag of `textarea` will never change, unless you add some code to change it, and once you change `textContent`, the value will be changed respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I've added `jQuery` code.

Comment: As @freedomn-m said, I'm using jquery. My unexperienced me tagged JavaScript, I'm sorry for the confusion. In my jquery I currently check the condition if($textfield.text().trim() !== '' || if($textfield.val().trim() !== '') I will edit that in my question.

Comment: you have to check only for `val()` i.e. `if($textfield.val().trim() !== '')` because if you check for the `.text()`  it will always return `true` because the`text` will always be there as I explained in my answer.